# Subtracting two date fields

Tags: sql, date, diff, datediff, subtraction

I have two date fields and I am trying to subtract them to come up with the difference in days. I am using Oracle SQL server.

```
select LST_MOD_TS-EFF_DT as DATE_DIFF from TABLE1;
```

This gives me the following output:

```
+01 04:08:33.000000
```

I would like it formatted as '1' so I do not need the '+' or '-' sign, and I do not need the date portion in the return.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I meant that I do not need the time portion in the return, apologies!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `EXTRACT` Function

```
SELECT EXTRACT(day FROM LST_MOD_TS)-(day FROM EFF_DT) AS DATE_DIFF 
FROM TABLE1;
```

Comment: this doesn't run.. says 'missing right parenthesis'.